# Make a table in R that resembles facet_grid in structure

Tags: r

I would like to make a "nested" sort of table in R that mirrors the formatting of a plot I can make with ggplot using facet_wrap.

Here are some data and the code:

```
tabledata = structure(list(row = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                       col = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                       grp1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                        .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
                       grp2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                        .Label = c("g", "h"), class = "factor"), 
                       value = c(9L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L)), 
                  .Names = c("row", "col", "grp1", "grp2", "value"), class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c(NA, -16L))

ggplot(tabledata, aes(grp2, value, shape = grp1)) + geom_jitter() + facet_grid(row ~ col)
```

Which produce this plot:
[image]

Here is the table I would like to make (which can easily be done with a pivot table, but obviously that is not ideal):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested table can be made using the `tabular()` function in the `tables` package using the following code.

```
tabular(
    (Heading()*Factor(row)*Heading()*grp1)~
    (Heading()*Factor(col)*Heading()*grp2)*Heading()*value*Heading()*identity, 
data = tabledata)
```

The table can then be saved as a .csv file using `write.csv.tabular()`.

Answer (score -1):

Tidyverse just added a table package that has the nested format built in. It's called "gt" (great tables) https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/04/08/great-looking-tables-gt-0-2/